# Should we have an egyptian fractions tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

Just a thought that there are enduring questions of this kind, and tagging them might help identifying themes and duplicates. As always this is tentative.

---

So here are some examples from some 20 questions which mention the term. Possibly this is not enough, as there are some duplicates there, but there are also questions which don't. There is a fractions tag, which is possibly enough, but it isn't consistently used for  these examples.

[This basic question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17176/find-proof-egyptian-fractions-and-modified-euclidean-algorithm)

[Another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199277/optimal-decomposition-of-fracmn/199281#199281)

[Pretty much a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238496/a-question-about-rational/238511#238511)

[Something different](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21969/can-the-sums-of-two-sequences-of-reciprocals-of-consecutive-integers-be-equal/21970#21970)

[Another example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387500/a-formula-by-r-l-graham-amm1995)

[Not quite what I was thinking of](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321442/a-question-on-paul-erdoss-research-on-egyptian-fractions)

[This is the one which triggered my thought](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455159/smallest-n-with-given-number-of-solutions-of-frac1u-frac1v-fra) - it doesn't mention Egyptian Fractions at all

Comment: I think it would be useful.

Comment: I agree with @AndresCaicedo It would be even more useful if you can write a tag wiki for it. `:-)`

Comment: @WillieWong, created a tag and a vanilla tag wiki. I'm not sure people know what that is, i didn't when you talked about it for "complex-multiplication"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put such a tag at [Fractions in Ancient Egypt](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458238/fractions-in-ancient-egypt)   and put something as the "tag-wiki" which, well, is not necessarily very good. On the other hand, in this case there is unlikely to be genuine confusion. Anyone with 20K can edit the tag wiki. This is the sole and entire benefit of reaching 20K.

Friday, 2 August.

I tagged two more from your list, three seems enough for me to do at once.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/egyptian-fractions

Comment: I'm not at $20k$ yet - thanks for adding

Comment: @MarkBennet, I think the way it works is this: you can create a tag. However, the liitle description that goes with it will remain blank until a moderator or 20K fills that in. I created a "complex-multiplication" tag, Willie was concerned that users would think it was about how to multiply complex numbers, until he looked up   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_multiplication and filled in the "tag wiki" That's what he was asking you for on July 30, suggested text for a tag wiki.

Comment: @MarkBennet, WillJagy: Users bellow 20k can edit tag-wikis and tag-excerpt, but it will be a [suggested edit](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/suggested-edits/info) and it will have to be reviewed by two 10k+ users. If you have a look at [history of suggested edits](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history), it seems that suggested edits on meta are usually of this type.

Comment: You can use `[tag:tag-name]` to generate an automatic link to the tag.